# Как запустить .bat файл через python?

Tags: python, bat, subprocess

Пытаюсь запустить bat-файл через python, но не выходит. Есть bat-файл, который запускает сервер для игры Valheim. Напрямую он запускается нормально. Пытаюсь запустить через python, пишет что `C:\ProgramData\ServerValheimPVE\ServerBackupsWorlds\scripts>valheim_server -nographics -batchmode -name "[RU] Valheim<color=#94ACD2>PVE</color> discord.gg/uS42Rb9AsA" -port 2457 -world "VlhmPVESrv" -password "" -savedir  C:\ProgramData\ServerValheimPVE\SaveDataValheim "valheim_server" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`

```
import os
import sched, time
from threading import Timer
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from subprocess import call

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
print('КОД backup.py ЗАПУЩЕН!')
call("C:\\ProgramData\\ServerValheimPVE\\valheim\\startPVE.bat")

def backupserver(event):
        
    source = ['C:\\ProgramData\\ServerValheimPVE\\SaveDataValheim\\worlds']
    target_dir = 'C:\\ProgramData\\ServerValheimPVE\\ServerBackupsWorlds\\backups'
    target = target_dir + time.strftime(' %Y-%m-%d %H %M %S') + '.7z'
    zip_command = 'C:\\"Program Files"\\7-Zip\\7z a -t7z "%s" %s' % (target, ' '.join(source))

    if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
        print ('Successful back up to', target)
    else:
        print ('Backup FAILED')

    s.enter(60, 1, backupserver, (event,))

    s.enter(60, 1, backupserver, (s,))
    s.run()
```

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет опыта в питоне, но я могу предположить, что у os.system есть понятие "команды" и "параметров". Грубо говоря, как argv[] в c++. Тогда нужно просто эту сложную команду - вызов скрипта с параметрами - разделитт на части - "команду" и "аргументы", и правильно их передать в функцию - запускатор.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно просто запустить батник то сменим рабочую директорию:

```
os.chdir('полный путь до файла')
```

Затем нужно запустить через ос

```
os.system('start [название батника]')
```